# Order of evaluation in find

Tags: find, solaris

I've been dealing with the man pages and do not know how find performs order of the tests.

Please note that Solaris' find command do not have "tests" and "actions" separatedly, but just tests as pieces of the expression.

In this case, for command line like

```
find . -type d -mount -ctime +5 -prune -exec 'rm {}' \;
```

Is it guaranteed that "-type d" and "-ctime +5" are evaluated before "-exec 'rm {}' \;" and thus, only the correct files are deleted?

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, but I don't think `rm {}` should be quoted. You can quote `{}` if your shell will interpret it first in some way, or leave it unquoted in most shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation**

The various implementations of `find` tend to call the `operands` different names in the `man` page. However the general execution of any `find` implementation that follows the `posix` standard is going to be the same.

```
find [-H | -L] path ... [operand_expression ...]
```

*man page quotes taken from [posix find man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/find.html)*

Where each set of two touching `expressions` (meaning `-operand (Argument)`), that does not have explicit operator separating the `expressions`, has an implicit `-a` (AND) operator separating them.

```
expression  [-a]  expression
Conjunction of primaries; the AND operator is implied by the juxtaposition of 
two primaries or made explicit by the optional -a operator. 
The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is false.
```

**Conclusion**

So any implementation that follows the `posix` standard must execute `expressions` left to right; and

```
find . -type d -mount -ctime +5 -prune -exec 'rm {}' \;
```

is equivalent to

```
find . -type d  -a -mount -a -ctime +5 -a -prune -a -exec 'rm {}' \;
```

Meaning that `-exec` will only be executed if all preceding `operands` are true.

**Other**

It's also worth noting that while `-exec` may not be called an explicit `action` by your find implementation, it should still get treated in a similar manner (namely replacing the `-print` action)

```
If no expression is present, -print shall be used as the expression. 
Otherwise, if the given expression does not contain any of the primaries -exec, 
-ok, or -print, the given expression shall be effectively replaced by:

( given_expression ) -print
```

**Edit**

Technically true that not every implementation has to be posix complaint. He're the almost identical quote from [solaris find man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7m9j/index.html)

```
expression [-a] expression
Concatenation of primaries (the and operation is implied by the juxtaposition of two primaries).
```

Comment: This does not "guarantee" as requested but is near enough. Many thanks.

Comment: @Envite True that not every implementation has to be `posix` compliant. Added quote from `solaris find` man page.

Comment: Yes, exactly the one I saw, with no explicitation of "The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is false." which lead me to the question.

Comment: @Envite Agreed, definitely should add that to their man page, or at least that they're using short circuit evaluation.